Test suite to cover repository where all tests are run at once on python
My tests are run correctly when I run them one by one, but failed interfering each other if I run them in test suite.
/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 789, in _handle_exception
    raise translated_error from error
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.InterfaceError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

I try to simplify the scenario and wrote a Repository which encapsulates CRUD operations to database.
I wrote a test suite which covers this repository by test.
However the first launch shown exception which I haven't figured out yet.
async def create_inventory(self, inventory_data: dict) -> None:
>       async with self.database.get_async_session() as session:
E       AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'get_async_session'

@pytest.fixture
async def test_database() -> Database:
    """Fixture for setting up a test database."""
    # Initialize the Database
    db = Database()
    
    # Create the database tables if needed
    async with db.get_async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            # Here you might want to create your tables for tests
            await session.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    yield db  # This provides the db instance to the tests

    # Teardown can go here if necessary
    async with db.get_async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            await session.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)  
    
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_inventory(test_database: Database):
    """Test creating a new Inventory record."""
    repo = InventoryRepository(test_database)
    inventory_data = {
        "time": 1234567890,
        "flight": "FL456",
        "departure": 9876543211,
        "flight_booking_class": "Economy",
        "idle_seats_count": 15
    }
    
    await repo.create_inventory(inventory_data)

    new_inventory = await repo.get_inventory(
        flight=inventory_data["flight"], 
        flight_booking_class=inventory_data["flight_booking_class"]
    )
    
    assert new_inventory.flight == inventory_data["flight"]
    assert new_inventory.idle_seats_count == inventory_data["idle_seats_count"]

Repository and database layers:
class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Database credentials
        self.db_username = os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER', "myuser")
        self.db_password = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', "mypassword")
        self.db_name = os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB', "mydatabase")
        self.db_host = os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')
        self.db_port = os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT', 5432)
        
        # Ensure all necessary environment variables are set
        if not all([self.db_username, self.db_password, self.db_name, self.db_host]):
            raise ValueError("Missing one or more environment variables for source or sink database.")

        # Database URLs
        self.sqlalchemy_database_url = (
            f"postgresql+asyncpg://{self.db_username}:{self.db_password}@"
            f"{self.db_host}:{self.db_port}/{self.db_name}"
        )

        # Create async engines
        self.engine = create_async_engine(self.sqlalchemy_database_url, echo=True)

        # Async session makers for each database
        self.AsyncSourceSessionLocal = async_scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(
                bind=self.engine,
                class_=AsyncSession,
                autocommit=False,
                autoflush=False,
            ), scopefunc=current_task
        )
    
    async def get_async_session(self) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
        return await self.AsyncSourceSessionLocal() 
    
class InventoryRepository:
    def __init__(self, database: Database) -> None:
        self.database = database

    async def create_inventory(self, inventory_data: dict) -> None:
        async with self.database.get_async_session() as session:
            async with session.begin():
                stmt = insert(Inventory).values(**inventory_data)
                await session.execute(stmt)

    async def get_inventory(self, flight: str, flight_booking_class: str) -> Optional[Inventory]:
        async with self.database.get_async_session() as session:
            stmt = select(Inventory).where(
                Inventory.flight == flight,
                Inventory.flight_booking_class == flight_booking_class
            )
            result = await session.execute(stmt)
            return result.scalar_one_or_none()

Could you please me figure out how to overcome this issue or give me a correct example how to cover this scenario right by tests which could run as a test suite?

How about rename async def test_database to async def testing_database?

I would appreciate your input even if it is intended to readability of the code, but your intent is different, isn't it? Shall we move politics out of this platform and get back to a genuine team working on technical & business issues as it is widespread in the global community of engineers?

Hi, you!
First of all, I made a mistake that leave a rename suggestion without explain why (I think pytest.fixture does not allow to patch a function whose name startswith test_)
Secondly, it is a politeness to save helper's time by offer a fully example including imports, so that others can copy it to a file and run python xxx.py to reproduce the issue.
Thirdly, I am angry and not happy to see these words: Shall we move politics out of this platform...
Finally, as the document says you may need to use @pytest_asyncio.fixture instead of @pytest.fixture
